# No Internet access when VirtualBox is installed with networking

Tags: virtualbox

How can I set Windows XP to access the Internet when I have installed VirtualBox with networking (the one that I have to check when installing VirtualBox)?

Because ever since that, I encountered the problem of not being able to access the Internet because of VirtualBox networking. I didn't install the functionality anymore. Can I enable the function without having to sacrifice my Internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default networking mode for VirtualBox should enable both host and guest systems to connect to the Internet.

See the section on [Network Address Translation (NAT)](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) in the documentation for further details.